# Sharepoint: use mailto command to send subject and body

Tags: email, sharepoint, mailto, subject

I am developing in SharePoint and I would like to prepare a mailto command but I would like to send two values to the email and not just one. Normally in html the command works

```
<a href="mailto:email@here.com?subject=The%20Subject&body=The%20Body">Email</a>
```

But in SharePoint I seem to only be able to send the first section after the *email@here.com?*. Depending on what I position first, I sometimes get the **@Body** field to go through or the **@Title** to go through. It appears that for some reason the "**&**" isn't accepted. I also tried **%26** in the place of & with no result.

What is the best method to get both (body and subject) to go through to the mail-client?

Thank you in advance for your time, any guidance will be greatly appeciated